# Mysterious android notification channel created on Samsung devices

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am working on an app which requires me to create some custom notification channels. Everything worked fine, until I tested the app on a samsung device. For some reason, a channel with id "ACCOUNT" is created, but not by my app. I searched for this behaviour on google and in the android docs but I couldn't find any related information.

```
NotificationChannel{mId='ACCOUNT', mName=Account status, mDescription=, mImportance=2, mBypassDnd=false, mLockscreenVisibility=-1000, mSound=content://settings/system/notification_sound, mLights=false, mLightColor=0, mVibration=null, mUserLockedFields=0, mFgServiceShown=false, mVibrationEnabled=false, mShowBadge=true, mDeleted=false, mGroup='null', mAudioAttributes=AudioAttributes: usage=USAGE_NOTIFICATION content=CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION flags=0x800 tags= bundle=null, mBlockableSystem=false, mAllowBubbles=-1, mImportanceLockedByOEM=false, mImportanceLockedDefaultApp=false, mOriginalImp=2, mParent=null, mConversationId=null, mDemoted=false, mImportantConvo=false}
```

I use Infobip as the notification provider, but channel is not created by it as I looked in their source code - they only create 2 channels, which I've already removed.

```
"mm_default_channel_high_priority",
"mm_default_channel",
```

For some other functionality, the app also creates an Android account, but the name doesn't match with the notification channel id.

```
accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, null, null)
```

Did anyone experience this issue? If not, is there any way to trace back who/what is creating this notification channel?